# Configure RavenDB versioning via code

Tags: ravendb

Is it possible to configure versioning on a new RavenDB database via code?

I'm using the following code (based on http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/versioning):

```
Store.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(database);
using (var session = Store.OpenSession(database))
{
    session.Store(new 
        {
            Exclude = false,
            Id = "Raven/Versioning/DefaultConfiguration",
            MaxRevisions = 5
        });
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I add and modify records in the database versioning is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is good, but it just creates the configuration information that the Versioning Bundle will look for.  It doesn't actually enable the bundle.

For any *named* bundle, you enable it by including the name in the `Raven/ActiveBundles` setting, which is a semicolon-delimited list of bundle names.

By "named" bundles, I mean those that export a `"Bundle"` name using the `[ExportMetadata]` attribute.  All of the built-in bundles do this.  (You can see that the Versioning Bundle exports the name `"Versioning"` if you dig into the [source code of one of its triggers](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Bundles/Versioning/Triggers/VersioningPutTrigger.cs)).

If a bundle is *unnamed* then it is always enabled, as long as it exists either within the RavenDB server assemblies, or in a separate assembly in the `\plugins` folder.

It looks like the documentation needs updating, as it still says to place the `Raven.Bundles.Versioning.dll` assembly in the plugins folder.  That no longer exists, as it was moved into the main RavenDB server assemblies in 2.0.  So for this particular bundle, just editing the settings will be sufficient.

The settings for a named tenant database are kept in the system database in a document called `Raven/Databases/<YourDatabaseName>`.  Simply edit this document once, and the bundle is activated.  Here is an extension method that will do that for you:

```
public static void ActivateBundle(this IDocumentStore documentStore, string bundleName, string databaseName)
{
    using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        var databaseDocument = session.Load<DatabaseDocument>("Raven/Databases/" + databaseName);

        var settings = databaseDocument.Settings;
        var activeBundles = settings.ContainsKey(Constants.ActiveBundles) ? settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] : null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeBundles))
            settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] = bundleName;
        else if (!activeBundles.Split(';').Contains(bundleName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] = activeBundles + ";" + bundleName;

        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Using the above method, you can simply call:

```
documentStore.ActivateBundle("Versioning", "YourDatabaseName");
```

If you are running an embedded-mode database, there are no named tenant databases, so the procedure is a bit different.  You can put settings into your own app.config file, or you can manipulate the `documentStore.Configuration.Settings` dictionary before your existing call to `documentStore.Initialize()`.  Here is a revised version of the extension method that will work on an embedded database:

```
public static void ActivateBundle(this EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore, string bundleName)
{
    var settings = documentStore.Configuration.Settings;
    var activeBundles = settings[Constants.ActiveBundles];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeBundles))
        settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] = bundleName;
    else if (!activeBundles.Split(';').Contains(bundleName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] = activeBundles + ";" + bundleName;
}
```

Using this method, you can simply do this:

```
documentStore.ActivateBundle("Versioning");
documentStore.Initialize();
```

Comment: Matt, can i recommend changing the opening of the session to `documentStore.OpenSession("<system>")` ?