# RavenDB Embedded Versioning not working

Tags: .net, ravendb

I'm trying to use the Versioning bundle in RavenDB embedded but I can't seem to query the revisions.

I'm initializing the database with this code in Global.asax.cs

```
// Initialise RavenDB embedded
Store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    DataDirectory = "~/App_Data",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
};

Store.ActivateBundle("Versioning");
Store.Initialize();
```

The ActivateBundle method is an extension method: (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202434/configure-ravendb-versioning-via-code))

```
    public static void ActivateBundle(this EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore, string bundleName)
{
    var settings = documentStore.Configuration.Settings;
    var activeBundles = settings[Constants.ActiveBundles];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeBundles))
        settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] = bundleName;
    else if (!activeBundles.Split(';').Contains(bundleName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        settings[Constants.ActiveBundles] = activeBundles + ";" + bundleName;
}
```

I'm querying for the revisions with this code:

```
        public IList<FormRevision> GetRevisions(Guid formId)
    {
        using (var session = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession())
        {
            var revisions = session.Advanced.GetRevisionsFor<Form>(formId.ToString(), 0, 10);

            return revisions.Select(formRevision => session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(formRevision)).Select(metadata => new FormRevision
            {
                FormId = formId, 
                RevisionNumber = metadata.Value<int>("Raven-Document-Revision"), 
                RevisionDateTime = metadata.Value<DateTime>("Last-Modified")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The GetRevisionsFor method is not returning any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/versioning),

> By default, the Versioning bundle will track history for all documents and never purge old revisions.

It turns out that for the embedded database, the versioning configuration document must be added.

```
        using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(new
            {
                Exclude = false,
                Id = "Raven/Versioning/DefaultConfiguration"
            });
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This code is in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202434/configure-ravendb-versioning-via-code), but I didn't add it originally after reading about the default configuration in the online documentation.  As it turns out, this document must be added for versioning to work.