# How to query RavenDB for the active Bundles

Tags: c#, ravendb

In RavenDB, how can you query the server's active bundles? And, how can you query the database's active bundles?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the database settings for that. The property that you want to look is "Raven/ActiveBundles" which I believe is declared as a constant under Constants.ActiveBundles.

For a more detailed answer please take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202867/3499186) from Matt.